# How to make buttons in sprite kit scenes animate as buttons (from view controller)?

Tags: objective-c, animation, button, sprite-kit

I am developing a game in sprite kit and have been using SKSpriteNode's as buttons. I have done much research and it seems that the 'best practices' way of developing a game is to use several sprite-kit-scenes on a single view controller and transitioning between the SKScenes.

However, the SKSpriteNode's do not have the press-down animation that buttons added to the view controller have. That is, if I add a button to the view controller and change its image to Spaceship.png, when I click it in Build&Run, it animates (looks like it the alpha property is getting changed, maybe to something around 0.5). Additionally, if you keep the button pressed, it will not execute its action until you let go. Furthermore, if you keep it pressed and move your mouse/finger away, it will return to its original state (not executing the action, and alpha set back to 1.0).

I was wondering if there was a method that does these things for SKSpriteNode buttons? I have found code that changes the texture/image (not what I want to accomplish), and I have not found code that allow the SKSpriteNode to not execute until you let go or canceling-touch effect (last two sentences of previous paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *spriteA;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {           
        spriteA = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        spriteA.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:spriteA];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    if([spriteA containsPoint:touchLocation])
        spriteA.alpha = 0.5;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(spriteA.alpha == 0.5)
        spriteA.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sangony above! Using your logic I added a little bit (you had the alpha fade, i added code to make it cancel event) and I just wanted to post my final code here in case anyone else comes across this:

```
@implementation LTMyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *spriteA;
    SKLabelNode *labelCounter;
    int intCounter;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        intCounter=0;
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        spriteA = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];//[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        spriteA.size=CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        spriteA.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:spriteA];

        labelCounter = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thirteen Pixel Fonts"];
        labelCounter.fontSize=12.0;
        labelCounter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter is: %i",intCounter];
        labelCounter.name = @"HighScoreLabel";
        labelCounter.verticalAlignmentMode=SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
        labelCounter.position=CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/4);
        [self addChild:labelCounter];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    if([spriteA containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
        spriteA.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    if(spriteA.alpha == 0.5) {
        if([spriteA containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
            intCounter=intCounter+1;
            labelCounter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter is: %i",intCounter];
        }
        spriteA.alpha = 1.0;
    }
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) move this code to a subclass of SKSpriteNode called something like Button and 2) override touchesMoved to set alpha = 1.0 if the user moves his/her finger off the button (to better mimic the behavior of UIButton). You can remove the if statement with containsPoint in the touchesEnded since alpha will be 1.0, appropriately.